# How to override a control method that created by scene builder

Tags: javafx, overriding, scenebuilder

I create a window by **scene builder** and I want to override some controls `gettext()` and `paste()` method. But I don't know how to do it because I didn't create these controls by coding but by scene builder.
How can I **override** these controls methods?

Comment: For most, if not all, controls with a `getText()` method, that method is final anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, you have to extend the custom control class (If it's not final class) to override any of it's methods.